# Discord python bot missing required position argument

Tags: python

So im trying to make my bot post to discord but im having so much trouble when i run my script it says "messing argument required position arguemnt 'id'

```
client = discord.Client





async def hello_world():
await client.send_message(client.get_server('401428140913590272'), 
content=None, tts=False, embed=None)`

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(hello_world())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing the client token that discord gave you
Additionally instead of `client = discord.Client` it should be `client = discord.Client()` a method not a property.

Finally when you run the bot you are missing `client.run(TOKEN HERE)`

Comment: It's hard to help you without more details @milo217 can you add more details and give a stack trace?

Comment: yea that worked for getting rid of the error but it just doesent post to any channels i am using this code as the send message bit     await client.send_message(client.get_server('401428140913590272'), "test", tts=False)

Comment: `content=None` shouldn't your message go in there?

Comment: i get the error    discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType

Comment: I recommend you consulting the api documentation at this point my guess is you are mis-using the api.

Comment: I can’t seem to find any information on there regarding how to formart destination like regarding setting the server and the channel